# JScrollPane is not working, viewport is stacking panels

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane, viewport

This is the class where program is being run.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class runClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(1366, 768);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JPanel backgroundPanel = new JPanel();
    backgroundPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 1366, 768);
    backgroundPanel.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    frame.getContentPane().add(backgroundPanel);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1,10,10));

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(228, 5, 453, 426);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);
    scrollPane.setVisible(true);
    backgroundPanel.setLayout(null);
    backgroundPanel.add(scrollPane);

    for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++){
        panel.add(new ExerciseList(new Exercise("hello")));
    }

    panel.revalidate();
    panel.repaint();

}
}
```

This is the panels that are being added into the container.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Font;

public class ExerciseList extends JPanel{

    private Exercise exercise;

    public ExerciseList(Exercise e){

        this.exercise = e;

        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        JLabel lblName = new JLabel(exercise.getName());
        lblName.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        lblName.setBounds(229, 11, 209, 22);
        add(lblName);

    }
}
```

This is the exercise class the is used to retrieve information for ExerciseList.

```
public class Exercise {

    private String name;

    public Exercise(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

This is an image of the stacking of ExerciseList that I am getting.

[As you can see, the ExerciseList panels are overlapping, rather than the JScrollPane allowing me to scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sa6eh.png)

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: For better help sooner please post a valid [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. Probably related to the mix of a [Layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and `setBounds()`. However for your GUI you might want to try using a [`JTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html)

Comment: Okay thanks! I prefer to stay with this GUI layout. So where can the issue stem from both the layout manager and setbounds()?

Comment: The issue is that you can't and shouldn't do that. Let the layouts and the components own preferred sizes set their actual size, otherwise the GUI is displayed in funny ways as you're seeing.

Comment: It looks as if you might want to consider using a JTable display and interaction with tabular data. But if not, then smarter use of layout managers will be your salvation.

Comment: The issue comes from the `setBounds()` calls. Remove them and if problem persists, then take the [tour], while you go through the [help] and read [ask] and then post a valid [mcve] that we can copy-paste and see the same issue as you

Comment: I updated the post, but am still having the issue with a more simple program.

I am unsure of your approach, when you are asking me to remove setBounds() calls, can you be more specific Frakcool? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the problem: you're using `null` layouts, a layout that JScrollPanes are not equipped to deal with and that should be avoided as a general rule. Get rid of this:

```
// setLayout(null);
```

and your problems go away. Why is this a problem? Both a container's layout manager and its components help determine the preferred size of the container and its components. If null layouts are used, then this does not happen, and so the viewport's view (the JPanel held by the JScrollPane) will not expand as it should when more components are added.

While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

Learn the layout managers.

Then use them.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ExerciseDemo extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 500;
    private static final int PREF_H = 450;
    protected static final int MAX_COUNTER = 30;
    private JPanel exerciseHolder = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));

    public ExerciseDemo() {
        JPanel wrapperPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        wrapperPanel.add(exerciseHolder, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(wrapperPanel);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(scrollPane);

        new Timer(300, new ActionListener() {
            int counter = 0;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                counter++;
                exerciseHolder.add(new ExerciseList2(new Exercise("John Smith " + counter)));
                exerciseHolder.revalidate();
                exerciseHolder.repaint();
                if (counter > MAX_COUNTER) {
                    ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        ExerciseDemo mainPanel = new ExerciseDemo();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ExerciseDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ExerciseList2 extends JPanel {
    private static final Font NAME_FONT = new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18);
    private Exercise exercise;

    public ExerciseList2(Exercise exercise) {
        this.exercise = exercise;

        JLabel lblName = new JLabel(exercise.getName());
        lblName.setFont(NAME_FONT);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 3, 3, 3));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(15, 0));
        add(new JCheckBox("Check Box"), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        add(lblName, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(new JButton("Button"), BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    }    

    public Exercise getExercise() {
        return exercise;
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the information. I will take that into mind as I do more GUIs. Thanks alot!

Comment: @gary.l: for example, compile and run the above code. It requires your Exercise class to work.